# Dealing with Fetching Data and Multilple ngFors

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm currently building an application in Ionic where I am fetching data from a firebase database that I want to display. I want to display posts, which have some text, a title and possibly a imgurl. Essentially, I want to loop over multiple arrays and display these three things separately but I can't do that with ngFor. I can't use an index variable either since there is no way that I know of to fetch an item by its "id" in angularfire2.

```
import {FirebaseListObservable } from '...'


constructor (private fbs: FirebaseService){
fbs.getPosts(); // returns a FirebaseListObservable from a defined service
fbs.getTitles();
fbs.getImgUrl();

}
```

**Html**

```
<ion-card *ngFor = 'let post of posts' >
<ion-card-header> // here i want to have the title associated with the first post</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>{{post.$value}}</ion-card-content>¨
<img src = //here i want to have the img appropiate to the post>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: Are the three arrays related to one thing? Without some code/ability to conceptualise a data model, see service calls, and code it's hard to answer. You need to embellish your answer to be able to give a definitive answer.

Comment: You know that there is a documentation link on Stack Overflow too right? You'll be able to find topics about most of the tags you've applied to this question.

Comment: Edited @JGFMK ...